# Find all possibilities to split a set of non-necessarily disjoint elements (prime factors for example) into two subsets.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

To find all possibilities of splitting a set of non-necessarily disjoint elements, let's take the $8$ prime factors $e~e~f~g~h~h~h~h$ for example, into two subsets:

- How many possibilities exist? (Important question)
- How can I determine all these possibilities in a structured way? (extra question)

The order of these elements does not matter. To start with the given example we would have:

1. $(e)$ and $(e~f~g~h~h~h~h)$
2. $(e~e)$ and $(f~g~h~h~h~h)$
3. $(e~e~f)$ and $(g~h~h~h~h)$

$\ldots$

4. $(e~h~h)$ and $(e~f~g~h~h)$

and so on. To know how many possibilities exist, would be sufficient and helpfull enough.

Comment: If "() and (e e f g h h h h)" is included, this is equivalent to finding (half) the number of divisors of $e^2fgh^4$, which is equal to $(1/2)(3)(2)(2)(5) = 30$. Also see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Formulas_at_prime_powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Formulas_at_prime_powers).

Comment: Thank you very much - this is a very helpful link.

Comment: Do you consider the splittings $(e~e~f)-(g~h~h~h~h)$ and $(g~h~h~h~h)-(e~e~f)$ the same or different?

Comment: At this moment I consider these to be same. Otherwise I would have 60 instead of 30 cases.